# How to add integer array column to H2 Database

Tags: h2

`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_integers Integer[];`

`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_integers Array[Integer];`

Do not work.

`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_integers array;`

Works. But there's no type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. H2 1.x.y does not have typed arrays, there is no way to define them. You can use only the plain `ARRAY` data type. Of course, you can use it for integer values too.
2. H2 since the version 2.0.202 supports only standard-compliant typed arrays with the syntax from the SQL Standard (`INTEGER ARRAY`, `INTEGER ARRAY[10]` etc.)

https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type

Also take a look on the array literal grammar:

https://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#array

Please note that syntax of array literals was changed in H2 1.4.198 from H2-specific to the standard one. The online documentation is for the latest released version. If you use 1.4.197 or older version for a some reason, it has another syntax for array literals.